# How to access couchDB through a HTML page and display some db value in that page

Tags: couchdb

I have been searching this from past 4 days. I need to do a simple thing.
1) Create a HTML page.
2) Create a DB in couchDB.
3) Access the CouchDB from my HTML page.
4) Get the value and display the value form CouchDB in the HTML page.

I have gone through varrious docs available on internet, but failed to understand.
Please if anyone can explain the easy steps, it would be of great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB has a HTTP RESTful API. Everything is done by issuing HTTP requests with JSON data directly to the server, [as documented on the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Reference).

Cloudant has a nice article on [how to use Backbone to do this](https://cloudant.com/blog/backbone-and-cloudant/).

Answer (score 0):

- Try download CouchDb from [here](HTTP://couchdb.apache.org/) and install it.
- Go to Start-> All programs Apache CouchDb and start CouchDB.
- Try URL localhost:5984/_utils/ from your browser, you will be having option to create database and document.
- Try Jquery or Backbone.js to connect CouchDb with the HTML.